# Capture generated HTML output of JSF page

Tags: jsf

Does anyone have a class which I can run on the server side which will generate the HTML output of an xhtml JSF page that I can then use to email to clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class already exist in Java SE API: [`java.net.URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://localhost/context/page.jsf").openStream();
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do that but processing the xhtml with the Beans content?